# jQuery script + compatibility

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery script creates compatibility issues with other java/mootools script on my site - is there anything I can do to make it *more* compatible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[href^="http://"]').filter(function() {return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;}).attr('target', '_blank');
   });                     
</script>
```

Note - the script is designed to open external links in new windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, either replace all `$` with `jQuery`, or use jQuery's [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode which doesn't assign jQuery to `$`.

Or you could do this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[href^="http://"]').filter(function() {return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;}).attr('target', '_blank');
   });                     
</script>
```

...because the first argument to that anonymous function is the jQuery namespace. Here I have reassigned it to `$` internally.

It should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate on what you mean by compatibility issues.

It's possible you may need to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), especially when using jQuery in conjunction with other libraries such as MooTools.

However, since you already have MooTools, why not just use it instead?